# How to use the Trapezoidal method to find the Integral of a function in Python

Tags: python, integration

I'm trying to find the integral of the function below using the trapezoidal method however am not getting the right answer (which should be pi).
[Function Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdQNN.png)

The code I have implemented is below. Please let me know how I can edit it.

```
import numpy as np

def v(t):
    return np.sqrt(t - t**2)

def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
    h = (b-a)/n
    f_sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n, 1):
        x = a + i*h
        f_sum = f_sum + f(x)
    return h*(0.5*f(a) + f_sum + 0.5*f(b))

n = 1000

trap = trapezoidal(v, 0, 1/4, n)
ans = ((3*np.sqrt(3)/4)+24)*trap

print('Trapezoidal method, {} sub-intervals: {:.5f}'.format(n, ans))
print('Exact answer: 3.14159')
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have a wrong order of operations with your parens with the `ans` math. `24` should be multiplied by `trap` first, not added to the square root stuff first. It should be `ans = ((3*math.sqrt(3)/4))+24*trap`

```py
import numpy as np

def v(t):
    return np.sqrt(t - t**2)

def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n):
    h = (b-a)/n
    f_sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        x = a + i*h
        f_sum += f(x)
    return h*(0.5*f(a) + f_sum + 0.5*f(b))

n = 10000

trap = trapezoidal(v, 0, 1/4, n)
ans = ((3*np.sqrt(3)/4))+24*trap

print('Trapezoidal method, {} sub-intervals: {:.5f}'.format(n, ans))
print('Exact answer: 3.14159')
```